# How to show an image inside a VueJs v-for

Tags: vuejs2

How can i show an image inside a VueJs loop?

I do use : `<img src="/store/{{store.image}}">`

I try to show an image inside a v-for loop, but this situation shows this error message:

Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. 
Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. 
For example, instead of `<div id="{{ val }}">,` use `<div :id="val">`.

This is my v-for:

```
  <slide v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id" :store="store">                    
        <div class="rows is_block "> 
              <vue-flip active-click=1 class="is-block">
                <div slot="front">
                  <img src="/store/{{store.image}}">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic props are created using **colons**:

`<img :src="'/store/'+store.image">`

Check the docs for [Template Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes) and [Shorthands](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Shorthands)

Comment: Thank you @Slim, i try and your solution works just fine !